# What's the best to use id or !important?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Someone can say avoid using !important rule and someone can say id is unique so you don't need to target like `#main > #child` and just use `#child`.

But in my case:

```
#main > div{
   color: red;
}
#child{
  color: blue;/*won't override*/
}
```

1. But using `!important` will override.
2. Or, using `#main > #child{` will override.

So, which one is best to use?

Comment: Actually, I would rather not do `#main > div` but instead set a class on the `div` you want to style (`#main > .hasError`). That will also probably solve your issue. Styling tags is also a bad practice (as using !important)

Comment: Do not use id selectors in css. It wil only present you with alot of specificity problems and will either force frequent use of !important or unecessarily long selectors. Use class selectors instead.

Comment: @connexo That's what someone says but someone says do not use !important. So, which is the best way?

Comment: As I said, use ***neither***. Use classes instead.

Comment: I know that. But in these two condition, which one you would suggest?

Comment: You may better have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428759/how-does-css-rules-apply-and-override/31428760

Comment: Please upvotes answer in case they are useful, to be thankful of time and effort people invest on your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know the rule of order for the css:

```
#main > div{
   color: red;
}
#main > div{ /*last defined rule*/
  color: blue; /*will override*/
}
```

## Now, let's talk about your key question:

Using `!important` is not always bad thing. Look at below code [Commented by Marco Campos in css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/):

> I used it on a special ocasion for making IE9 keep the overflow as the normal browsers. In the case, on ie<9 it showed up a message telling the user to upgrade the browser, so in all the other browsers the contet would overflow normaly, but IE9 still understand some buged css, so i had to use !important to it render correctly.

```
body {
    overflow:auto !important; /* for all other browsers, the !important is for IE9 */
    overflow:hidden\9; /* for IE<9 */
}
```

Now, let's talk about [how css selector works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS):

> The style system matches rules by starting with the key selector, then moving to the left (looking for any ancestors in the rule’s selector). As long as the selector’s subtree continues to check out, the style system continues moving to the left until it either matches the rule, or abandons because of a mismatch.
>
> The fewer rules required to check for a given element, the faster style resolution will be.
>
> For example, if an element has an ID, then only ID rules that match the element’s ID will be checked. Only Class Rules for a class found on the element will be checked. Only tag rules that match the tag will be checked. Universal Rules will always be checked.

So, the selector `#main > #child` is worst than `#child` as it first matches `#child` and matches `#main`. Thus, I would avoid using `#main > #child` and recommend you to use just single element `#child`.

Ummm, wait! Would it be elegant solution using `#child{color: blue !important;}` then? It's merely difficult to override the rule.

We can still override them using simple parent element selector like this:

```
body #child{
    color: purple !important;
}
```

To say, exactly to your solution, it can be used like this so (without using !important and multiple id selector):

```
body div#child{ /*more specific than #main > div */
    color: blue; /*will override*/
}
```

There's also an easier solution using classes:

```
.parent-class #child{
    color: blue; /* will be the rule*/
}
#main > div{
    color: red;
}
```

Note: Using `!important` in inline-style would be mostly worst thing that this cannot be overridden from anywhere.

```
<div style="color: blue !important;">color is always blue</div>
```

Regarding to the question, exactly what should I use in between `#main > #child{color: blue;}` and `#child{color: blue !important;}`.

I would choose `#child{color: blue !important;}` as this can still be overriden and this is more faster than `#main > #child` selector.

Answer (score 0):

See [this explanation](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html#cascade). It describes the rule order.

I would try to avoid `!important` because it's the highest rule and you may find yourself in trouble, if you want to override it.

For you, I suggest `#main > #child`

Answer (score 0):

**The best practice is to target your style using the concept not the content.**

for example to make some thing red its better do it like:

```
<div class="red"></idiv>
```

and the CSS:

```
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

and if it has other property like beeing big, or wide or some other thing:

```
<div class="big red">
```

and the CSS:

```
.big{
    font-size: 2em;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Now**, having something to override you can just use `!important` and this way, you are avoiding using `ID`s  and you just better keep them for `JS` - `DOM Manipulation` purposes :)

---

**To Explain More**

This is a poor design:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main{
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: red;
}
#main > #child{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

because:

1. What if you decided to put `#child` higher or lower in hierarchy later? Please note that many designs would not be as simple as this example!
2. What is the conceptual meaning of `main:red` or `main:2em` combinations? that's better you consider `red:red` & `big:2em` combinations as these are far more flexible.

Comment: I know that. But I want to know which one is best in my condition?

Comment: As i said its better to use just classes and then just using !important for override purposes. using `ID`s like `#main > #child > #division` manner is not a good practice even for override purposes

Comment: If you style your document in such a way I described obove, using !important would not bother you and of course you will end up with a flexible design. trust me, I have developed more than a thousand of style sheets this way

Comment: @Trix It's never better to use `!important`. While I agree using ids (and especially more than one id in a selector) is bad practice, using `!important` is 1000x worse.

Answer (score -1):

Always try to avoid using `!important` i would go for your second option. Future changes in your css will be hard when you are using `!important`.

The only thing that can override an “!important” rule is another one, which must be specified lower down and its selector must have the same (or a higher) level of specificity.